# Left Join from three tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm taking a basic database course, and we got a question that I am struggling to find a good solution to.

We are to query a simplified SQLite NorthWind database for products that did not sell in April 2014.

I need to query three tables to get this, the Product, OrderItem and Order tables.  The OrderItem is the table with both ProductId and OrderId.  The Order table contains the OrderDate.

The lecture preceding this is about various joins, and I suspect this particulate problem involves left joins as I want to list products without entries in the OrderItem table after filetering Order by date.

Here is my query so far:

```
SELECT COUNT(OI.Id) AS Amount, P.ProductName, O.OrderDate
  FROM Product P 
  LEFT JOIN OrderItem OI ON P.Id = OI.ProductId 
  LEFT JOIN [Order] O ON O.Id = OI.OrderId
  WHERE O.OrderDate LIKE("Apr%2014%")
  GROUP BY P.ProductName
  HAVING Amount = 0
  ORDER BY Amount;
```

This returns an empty result set.  Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to solve this?

Comment: Never use `LIKE` on dates. ` O.OrderDate LIKE("Apr%2014%")` should be `strftime('%Y %m',O.OrderDate) = "2020 05" `

Comment: For orders when there is no entry in other tables you will get `O.OrderDate` as `NULL` in the left join.  But I would suggest using `NOT EXISTS `

Comment: That's true, but the datetime in this database is stored as a string with the format "Jul 18 2012 12:00:00:000AM".  I don't think strftime can parse that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend `not exists` for this:

```
select p.*
from products p
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from orderItem oi 
    left join [order] o on o.id = oi.orderId
    where 
        oi.product = p.id
        and o.orderDate >= '2014-04-01'
        and o.orderDate <  '2014-05-01'
)
```

I don't have a SQLite Northwind database at hand, but I would assume that dates are stored in a date-like format such as `yyyy-mm-dd`, hence the above expression to filter on April 2014. On the other hand, if they really used some custom format, you can stick to your `like` expression - the rest of the query remains the same.

Comment: This gave me the correct answer, thank you :)  The datefield was in a messy format so I had to use the LIKE expression.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for aggregation.
All you want is the products that do not match the left joins:

```
SELECT P.ProductName
FROM Product P 
LEFT JOIN OrderItem OI ON P.Id = OI.ProductId 
LEFT JOIN [Order] O ON O.Id = OI.OrderId AND O.OrderDate LIKE '%Apr%2014%'
WHERE O.Id IS NULL
```

The condition for the date is placed in the `ON` clause instead of a `WHERE` clause.
This will work if the format of your dates are like `%MMM%YYYY%` which is not a valid date format for SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `left join`.  But fix the date comparisons to use DATEs.  And move the condition to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT P.*
FROM Product P LEFT JOIN
     OrderItem OI
     ON P.Id = OI.ProductId LEFT JOIN
     [Order] O
     ON O.Id = OI.OrderId AND
        O.OrderDate >= '2014-04-01' AND
        O.OrderDate < '2014-05-01'
WHERE O.Id IS NULL;
```

It is unclear why you have a `GROUP BY`.  If you want the individual products, then no `GROUP BY` is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This seems to produce a cartesion cross product however. The GROUP BY was due to the agregate COUNT used in the query.

Comment: @Håkon . . . Clearly the count is not necessary, because you accepted an answer that doesn't have a count.  I'm not sure what you mean by "this seems to produce a Cartesian product".  This should be answering your question, using `LEFT JOIN`, which appears to be what you are asking.

Comment: Hi Gordon.  Your solution created a result set where each product in the database was listed several times.  It started like this:(1, 'Chai', 1, 18.0, '10 boxes x 20 bags', 0)
(1, 'Chai', 1, 18.0, '10 boxes x 20 bags', 0)
(1, 'Chai', 1, 18.0, '10 boxes x 20 bags', 0)
......  There was almost 2000 results returned with only about 100 products in the database.  That's what I ment with cartesian cross product.  The solution that worked did not use aggregate and therefore didn't need GROUP BY.